# Installing Tortoise SVN with elevated credentials

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, elevated-privileges

I'm trying to install TortoiseSVN (Ver: 1.6.1.16129) on Windows PC's where the user is not an administrator.

The installer is an msi file and by default, there is no "Run As" option for it.

I've tried both:

```
msiexec /a "{PATH}\TortoiseSVN-1.6.1.16129-win32-svn-1.6.1.msi"
```

and

```
runas /user:username "msiexec /a {PATH}\TortoiseSVN-1.6.1.16129-win32-svn-1.6.1.msi"
```

Running either of the above results in the installer starting then the first dialog has the cryptic message:
"Please specify a network location for the server image of Tortoise SVN 1.6...."

When the same msi file is run by a user who is an administrator, the installer proceeds as expected.

Has anyone else had this problem? Did you find a fix for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browse to the windows\system32 directory - right click on cmd.exe and choose "run as administrator". You get an elevated command shell. Now run your msi from the command shell.

Comment: Or press Start, search for 'cmd' and press Ctrl+Shift+Return (IMHO the fastest way to get an elevated prompt)

Answer (score 5):

Open task manager and kill the TSVNCache.exe process. Then try to install again.

Source:
http://dandar3.blogspot.fr/2012/04/tortoisesvn-installation-insufficient.html

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259459) might help.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to add to an old post.  However, I ran into this today and found a solution.  I used Runas on CMD.exe to get the elevated command prompt.  I then ran:

```
msiexec /i "{PATH}\TortoiseSVN-1.6.1.16129-win32-svn-1.6.1.msi"
```

Note: I replaced "/a" in the OP's post with "/i".  Once I changed that, then the network prompt was no longer asked during the installation.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today while updating Tortois and the root cause was that the C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN directory had somehow become marked read-only AFTER it had been emptied of the previous version's files. This might have something to do with the first attempt at updating tried to tell me that windows explore, tortoise svn shell and google chrome needed to be closed before continuing, and I selected the option to reboot later instead of closing. It prompted the same thing again before claiming it didn't have permissions to the directory.

So check the simple stuff first. Not even running as administrator can overcome a read-only directory flag.

If you look at the help for msiexec (using /h), it shows that /a is run as administrator network install. So it's just assuming you meant a network/remote location. I had no problem just pointing it to the local c: drive for installation and proceeding as normal.